# Fast Application Switching Is Slow Application Switching in Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have an issue I'm hoping someone can help with. I have an application that, for all intents and purposes, is working great. It's basically a picture viewer type of application - for something very specific. What it is is about 500 pictures.

I have all pictures set as Content and I load/unload one at a time. For the 500 pictures, I have a class that is used as data about each picture. So things like "place taken" , "index", "short description", etc. I never need to insert or delete from this list, but I may need to make some changes to each individual one, like "user viewed this picture on..." (date) or "favorite = true" (boolean where user marks a picture as a favorite picture).

When I deploy the app, this "picture metadata" is in xml file. It is then deserialized and saved to IsoStorage upon first run. A copy of it is maintained in memory and that is what is used to run my whole app. I have 3 different pages that all use that data, which is set as a static property in app.xaml.cs. Upon Deactivate/Closing the data is serialized back to xml - upon relaunching it is deserialized. Everything works fine and fast - everywhere. Including tombstoning.

The problem is resuming from Deactivation where the app is not tombstoned. It can take up to 10-15 seconds and definitely is returning from `e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved` in `Application_Activated` (i.e. it's not tombstoned).

Activating from brand new it takes about 3-4 seconds for the app to start. Returning from tombstoning it also takes about 3 seconds.

What I'm not understanding is why returning from `e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved = true;` is taking so long (and it won't allow me to pass certification). I've tested and found that if it is about 10 items in the `List` its incredibly snappy for FAS. If there are about 50 items in the `List` then it's not immediate. If there are 100 items, it's the first time you can see "Resuming..." (yep, that word coming from FAS, not tombstone). Where I have it, at 500 in the `List`, it is painfully slow to watch FAS, which is SAS.

It's interesting that in the emulator, FAS works perfectly fine, even with 1000 objects in memory. It's on an actual device where it is incredibly slow (Samsung Focus) in both debug and release mode.

Now I know the easy answer may be something like "why maintain a class with a list of 500 objects all the time?", but my whole architecture and user experience is based on having data about the pictures available on all three pages all the time. Linq is heavily used to report data everywhere.

Any thoughts or guidance on this situation?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but you have up to 500 pictures (Image files) being loaded at once? What's your memory footprint like? If it's greater than 90mb, you'll fail certification anyway, regardless of how long the FAS took.

Comment: @keyboardP: No, I don't have 500 pictures loaded at once. I have 500 objects in a `List` in a class being loaded at once and maintained throughout the application lifetime. The 500 objects are information about each picture (e.g. it's name, so it can be loaded into a canvas, when the picture was taken, is it a favorite, etc.) - mostly string and integer values in the object. Each object is being maintained in a `List` in a class. My memory footprint for the app never exceeds 30 MB either in the emulator or on the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great to hear you found the problem.

"sounds a serialization/deserialization issue to me. Are you storing the list in a State 'variable' ? were the framework will serialize when leaving the app and deserialize it when you return"

Comment: it appears that it was the built in serialization from `PhoneApplicationService.State` that was causing all the problems. Serialization - i.e. the stuff I serialize by myself - is fine, it's just that the `State` thing has slowed things down to a grinding halt. But your comment helped pointed me in the right direction as I wouldn't have thought it was this at all but rather some kind of memory issue. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, your PC + Emulator is MUCH faster and more powerful than your phone's 1GHz single core ARM processor with 500MB RAM!

When your app is activated with `e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved == true`, then you shouldn't need to restore any state and you should be able to pick up where the user left off.

If you're saying that when your list catalogs 500 items, the performance is horribly slow when resuming the app, I wonder whether you're also keeping the 500 images in memory and your phone is having to swap all that data into your app's memory space. This will be further compounded if your app has multiple pages each containing copies of your 500 images!

I **strongly** encourage you to **[profile your app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202934%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)** to measure its memory footprint and to see where the big memory, storage, IO and perf issues are.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I guess let me put this another way. I can launch my app and never load a single picture - just the class with the 500 objects (again, mostly string and int values). When I deactivate it and then FAS resume it, it will take more than 10 seconds. If I have only like ten or twenty objects in that class, it's incredibly fast. I've profiled my app and everything is smooth and works well. It's just FAS is es-el-oh-dubya, which the profiler isn't catching.

Comment: sounds a serialization/deserialization issue to me. Are you storing the list in a State 'variable' ? were the framework will serialize when leaving the app and deserialize it when you return.

Comment: @invalidusername: i believe you hit the nail on the head! please post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Great to hear this "solves" it. Posted it as an answer